# In the play framework, how do I run just one selenium test suite and have it run automatically?

Tags: tdd, playframework

I am doing Test Driven Development using the Play Framework and want to keep run the current failing test quickly.  I am finding clicking Start! to be to slow since I have a mostly keyboard driven workflow.  So ideally I would like a way to just reload the page and have it rerun the currently failing test.

Comment: "Premature optimization is the root of all evil"

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I ended up leaving play test running and reloading the following page - note the auto=yes parameter

http://localhost:9000/@tests?select=Application.test.html&auto=yes